# Oauth2. Asynchronous refresh_token calls

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, oauth-2.0

We have a client which communicates with a server secured by OAuth2.

As implementing tokens flow we have faced a problem. When page loads, there are few components that make calls to different secured endpoints. 
There is a situation when access token is expired so all requests get error and try to refresh it. So we have few asynchronous requests.

Is there an approach to deal with such situation?

Our client is written on React JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of solutions to this.

One solution would be to create something like a TokenService.

Before you fire any http call, you work with this service and check if you have a valid token. This is easy since when you create the token you get back information on how long the token is valid for. You store that somewhere and before you fire a call you check if you are still in the validity window. If you are then you fire the http call, if you are not then you request another and update the stored one with the new one. Once this is done then you fire your http call with the valid token.

If you don't want to manage this complexity then you could simply request a new token for every request and you're done. You use each token for one call and that's it really.

You could also use the refresh tokens functionality if you have that implemented, so if your token expires, you simply refresh it and move on

Comment: You just described not concurrent way of obtaining the access token. The question is about concurrent access to the same resource when access token is expired. We have implemented some sort of queue to synchronize requests sending in this situation. But thank you anyway for your answer!